Are the addedNodes and removedNodes properties of MutationRecord live or static NodeList objects?
I'm working with the MutationObserver API in JavaScript and I have a question about the addedNodes and removedNodes properties of the MutationRecord object.
When a mutation occurs and the MutationObserver callback is triggered, each MutationRecord object provides information about the changes that occurred. The addedNodes and removedNodes properties of such an object are NodeList objects representing the nodes that were added or removed during the mutation.
The MDN documentation [1][2] doesn't explicitly mention whether these NodeList objects are "live" or "static". How can I find out (by code)? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe there's a property of a NodeList object that can be accessed which can tell me if it's live or static.
Thanks!
[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord/addedNodes
[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord/removedNodes

"live" node lists change when the DOM changes (like, when a class is added or removed). How would that apply to this situation?

Actually, the NodeList objects are built as live in this case. But it seems it doesn't matter because everywhere they're built from static sets (apparently, I'd have to check the specs and lack time right now). So they'll behave just like static ones, even if internally they are live  NodeLists.

They are not live collections.
For the deletedNodes we can say they are not descendents any more of the observed container. To test whether it is a live collection we should add those elements back to the container and see if they are removed from that deletedNodes list we got earlier.
The addedNodes are descendants of the observed container. If we would remove them from that container later, then if that earlier addedNodes were a live list, we should see them being removed from that list.
Neither happens:


var lastAddedNodes;
var lastRemovedNodes;
// At first this element is not in the DOM:
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.textContent = "div created";

function log() {
  // Log the current size of the list we want to test for "liveness":
  console.log("is in lastAddedNodes?", lastAddedNodes?.[0] === div);
  console.log("is in lastRemovedNodes?", lastRemovedNodes?.[0] === div);
}

function onMutation(records) {
  for (const record of records) {
    if (record.type === "childList") {
      if (record.addedNodes.length && !lastAddedNodes) {
        // Save a reference to the node list in a global variable
        lastAddedNodes = record.addedNodes; 
      } 
      if (record.removedNodes.length && !lastRemovedNodes) {
        // Save a reference to the node list in a global variable
        lastRemovedNodes = record.removedNodes;
      }
    }
  }
  log();
}

const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const observer = new MutationObserver(onMutation);
observer.observe(container, { childList: true });

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log("adding element in container...");
  container.appendChild(div);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log("removing element from container...");
  container.innerHTML = "";
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log("adding element in container again...");
  container.appendChild(div);
}, 3000);

// Just to be sure, log the state some time later again
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log("final check...");
  log();
}, 4000);
<div id="container"></div>



We can see that if we capture the references to the node lists addedNodes and removedNodes at one point in time, these lists never change (size) later on, even if we move a node in or out the observed container. So they are not live lists.

The argument about deletedNodes makes no sense. If you expect the newly deleted node to not be part of the addedNodes anymore, ghen it would be part of the deletedNodes. Because a node is not connected doesn't mean it doesn't exist anymore.

@Kaiido, we agree it is not about existence, as then you could not have a reference to a node. This is about the interpretation of what "live" means. I took it to mean "descendant of a specific node". As deleted nodes are not descendents of anything, I discarded that possibility. I see we can also interpret it as being part of a collection that has the status "not descendent of node". I have extended the script to test the scenario where an earlier deleted node is made a descendent again of the observed container.

Note the tricky definition of "live" with deletedNodes, because if we use the definition "not descendent of observed node", then it should also contain nodes that were never in the container. So then the definition of "live" should become "not descendent of observed node, but once was". Anyway, it makes little sense to speak of "live" here, as the goal of the event is to give info about a transitional event, not a state.

"live" applies to the collection, not to the items that are collected. A "live" collection is one on which you check each item still matches the provided filter. For instance when we get a live collection through element.getElementsByClassName("foo"), every time we get an item in that collection we check whether that item  still is a descendant of element (because we called the method from there), and whether it still has the class foo. That's what "live" means. That has nothing to do with the fact the items are connected or not.

So yeah, it happens that the NodeLists in MutationRecords can not get mutated, but that has nothing to do with your explanation, and your tests hardly prove anything either.

That's what I mean with connected ("descendent" of element in your example). So I agree with you except with the conclusion that this script does not "prove anything". It proves that even if a node's condition changes in relation to whether its in the container or not (what is being observed), it still remains in the list, even though that doesn't match anymore the condition that node is in. It could be deleted and stil be in the added list, and it could be added again and still be in the deleted list.

But you still don't seem to understand that it's the collection that is live. So for instance, if there was (there isn't, it's just for the example) somewhere in the API a live collection of nodes that are present in a particular JS Set that the author can control, that collection would be dependent on the author's script. So the filter would be authorControlledSet.has(node). That's a very valid condition for a NodeList to be live, but your test obviously would miss that. And your answer is factually wrong: the NodeList is not created as static so it's live.

I do understand that a collection can be live. And we both understand that some kind of filter determines whether an element is in that collection or not. But in this context we know what that filter would be if it was present: the fact whether or not the node is currently considered deleted or added. Sure, we can think of completely unrelated filters, but I do not think that is realistic here. We are discussing the property of a node being added or being removed from the observed container and that is the sole reason why a node would have been placed in either of these two lists or not.

Still, these tests don't prove that. To prove that you need to got into the specs, to search for when every MutationRecord is queued, to verify it's indeed done from a static list in every situation. There may be a corner case neither of us can see right now where e.g an observed Attribute from a DOMFragment is added to a custom element inside a shadow DOM does something funky (such things may happen).

I have taken the definition of "live" to mean that there is a scenario where the list gets different members. The only scenario that makes sense is one where the filter relates to the conditions under which these lists were provided in the first place. My script changes these very conditions and the lists don't change. I am of the opinion that this is the only reasonable scenario to consider. If you disagree, then please post an answer that shows a case where one of these lists gets different members.
